# UI-Router Reload State without a full page refresh

Tags: angular-ui-router

Currently if I want to reload a state, I have to use the $state.reload().  This causes a full page refresh, which is very unfriendly.  I am looking for a way to just re-resolve my dependencies and reset the controller.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Just to add on @Dag 's answer:

Do note, as of [0.2.14](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/1809) you also have an option to just reload the current state and not it's parent.

So `$state.go(people.search, {}, {reload: true});` would reload the `people` state as well as all its childs.

While `$state.go(people.search, {}, {reload: "people.search"});` would not reload the `people` state but would reload `people.search` and its childs.

Answer (score 2):

you can try with:

```
$state.go($state.current.name, $state.params, { reload: true });
```

it will force transition even if the state or params have not changed without full page refresh. you can pass the state + the params + reload options.

for details look [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state) at "go" method.