# Is it possible to load different templates with attached controllers in same ui tab without state reload

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, uib-tabset

I have user angular ui-router to create nested states  in my application.
used abstract states also so that states should not get reloaded.

I use uib-tabs for one section which is child of other states , for one tab i need to render different templates based on button click event like add , edit, view
but these actions are defined as different states as different templates and controllers are used for these actions(form pages), it loads parent state templates as well as GET API calls which is not needed, want to load only tab specific templates and controllers only.
how can i achieve this or what could be best way to do this as i'm new to angular JS attaching code

// Code goes here

```
var loginInApp = angular.module('loginInApp', []);
loginInApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $qProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login');


$stateProvider

    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        views: {
           /* 'header': {
                templateUrl: 'header.html'
            },*/
            'login': {
                templateUrl: 'login.html',
                controller: 'LoginController',
             },
            'footer': {
                templateUrl: 'footer.html',
                controller: 'footerController'
            }
        }
     })
      .state('homeContainer', {
         url: '/homeContainer',
         templateUrl: 'homeContent.html',
         controller: 'homeContentController',
         controllerAs: 'homeContentCtrl',
         abstract : true,
         resolve:{              
        //webAPI calls
        }
     })

    .state('homeContainer.home', {
        url: '/home',
        views: {
            'header@homeContainer': {
                templateUrl: 'header.html',
                controller: 'HeaderController',
                controllerAs: 'Header',              
            },
            'folder@homeContainer': {//moved from home.content
                templateUrl: 'folder.html',
                controller: 'FolderController',
                controllerAs: 'Folder'
            },
            'content@homeContainer': {
                templateUrl: 'docAndNoteContent.html'
            },
            'emailSection@homeContainer': {
                templateUrl: 'emailSection.html',
                controller: 'EmailController',
                controllerAs: 'Email'
            },
            'footer@homeContainer': {
                templateUrl: 'footer.html',
                controller: 'footerController'
            }
        },
        abstract : true
    })
    .state('homeContainer.home.content', {
            url: '/content',
            views: {
                'documentAndNoteSection@homeContainer.home': {
                    templateUrl: 'documentAndNoteSection.html',
                    controller: 'documentAndNoteSectionController',
                    controllerAs: 'DocumentAndNotes'
                },
                'inbox@homeContainer.home': {
                    templateUrl: 'inbox.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'inboxController',
                    controllerAs: 'inbox'
                },
                'outbox@homeContainer.home': {
                    templateUrl: 'outbox.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'outboxController',
                    controllerAs: 'outbox'
                },
                'contacts@homeContainer.home': {
                    templateUrl: 'contacts.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'ContactController',
                    controllerAs: 'Contact'
                },
                'composeMail@homeContainer.home': {
                    templateUrl: 'composeMail.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'composeMailController',
                    controllerAs: 'composeMail'
                },
                'historyLog@homeContainer.home': {
                    templateUrl: 'historyLog.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'historyLogController',
                    controllerAs: 'historyLog'
                },
                'sharedItems@homeContainer.home': {
                    templateUrl: 'sharedItems.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'sharedItemsController',
                    controllerAs: 'sharedItems'
                }
            }
            abstract : true
    })
    .state('homeContainer.home.content.baseHomeState', { 
            url: '/baseHomeState',
            views: {
                'document@homeContainer.home.content': {
                    templateUrl: 'document.html',
                    controller: 'DocumentController'
                },
                'notes@homeContainer.home.content': {
                    templateUrl: 'note.html',
                    controller: 'NoteController',
                    controllerAs: 'Note'
                }
            }
    })
    .state('homeContainer.home.content.baseHomeState.addContact', { 
        url: '/addContact',
        views: {
            'contacts@homeContainer.home': {
                templateUrl: 'addContact.html',
                controller: 'AddContactController',
                controllerAs: 'AddContact'
             }
        }
    })

    .state('homeContainer.home.content.baseHomeState.editContact', { 
        url: '/editContact',
        views: {
            'contacts@homeContainer.home': {
                templateUrl: 'editContact.html',
                controller: 'EditContactController',
                controllerAs: 'EditContact'
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 0):

it is resolved [UI-Router Reload State without a full page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097221/ui-router-reload-state-without-a-full-page-refresh?rq=1)
$state.go(parentstatename, {}, {reload: "child state name"});
after reloading child state it doesnot reload parent put child state name in reload